# Getting "object has no attribute". (First time using class)

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm trying to create a frame with 3 frames inside using class (to add more frames in the future with ui button).First time I'm using class.
It gives me error, and I can't find in google what is the problem. It seems can't access variables stored in class object after creation, but ui builds correctly.(Error after pressing button)

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

names = [["123","456","789"]]

window.title("123")
window.geometry('400x250')
window.resizable(False, False)

def savebuttonfunc():
    for i in names:
        if type(i) != 'list':
            i = []
        i[0] = title.entry.get()
        i[1] = description.entry.get()
        i[2] = voicechat.entry.get()


top = Frame(window)
top.grid(row=0)
titletop = Label(top, text="Top")
titletop.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(5, 10))
savebutton = Button(top, text="Save", command = savebuttonfunc)
savebutton.grid(column=3, row=0, padx=(5, 10))

eb = Frame(window)
eb.grid(row=1)

class Entries:
    def __init__(self, column, width, text, id):
        self = Frame(eb)
        self.grid(row=1,column=column, padx=(5, 10))
        self.string_var = StringVar()
        self.entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.string_var, width=width)
        self.entry.grid(row=1)
        if not names[0][id]:
            self.string_var.set('123')
        self.string_var.set(names[0][id])
        self.txt = Label(self, text=text)
        self.txt.grid(row=0)

title = Entries(1,10, 'Title', 0)
description = Entries(2,25, 'Description', 1)
voicechat = Entries(3,7, 'VoiceChat', 2)

window.mainloop()
```

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\_DW\story of\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\delor\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.1\scratches\scratch_2.py", line 15, in savebuttonfunc
    i[0] = title.entry.get()
AttributeError: 'Entries' object has no attribute 'entry'
```

Comment: `self = ...` in your init is very wrong. You shouldn't rebind that name in your methods. I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) and look at what you used: `self.entry = Entry(...).grid(...)`

Comment: I presume "first time using class" in the question's title means this is your first time writing your own class. If this is the case, you'd benefit a lot from reading a good tutorial first.

Comment: @AndrasDeak How do I create frame in variable which calls this class in other way? I have tried self.frame = Frame(eb) , and put other things into self.frame, but result the same

Comment: @TheLizzard Yeah, thank you. I checked, and changed everywhere separately. But result is the same.

Comment: If you replaced `self = Frame(eb)` with `self.frame = Frame(eb)`  you should not see the same result. Can you update your code with this?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thank you, problem solved. I have tried with self.frame before and it's didn't worked, but for now it's working! Maybe i fixed something when i was preparing code for question.)